Graph API : add new metadata in onedrive Item
I'm trying to add or create new custom property to specific items in OneDrive. I tried using 'openExtension' with bellow request but failed (invalidRequest).
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!iy7xxxxxxu5XOy-gixxxxd2HB_kk/items/016xxO3N6xxxxxxxxx3IHZxx7Y6
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "openTypeExtension": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
        "extensionName": "com.contoso.customAttributes",
        "_AlreadyCheck": "YES"
    }
}

Please suggest.
